# Pass form inputs to page content

Tags: multisite, pages, forms, content

is it possible to pass form input to page content?
In a WordPress Multisite I’d like, when a user register and create his own website, to make him compile a form with the text and the photos that will replace website dummy content of the website page. Is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking to pass it before the form submit or after it is submitted?

Comment: I’m not sure to understand your question. I’d like that, when a user compile the form and hit the submit button, the content of the forms goes to some specific page area. For example, the “company description” text area form, will replace the box of text present in the about us website page.

Comment: You can do it with a plugin called formcraft and using their extended addon called form-to-post.

Comment: Thanks Debbie. Is it possible replace only some part of a page with that plugin? I doesn't load the documentation about that add-on so I can't verify.